# calculation of Detection, Recognition and Identification (DRI) ranges of a camera for different objects

Tags: camera, detection, image-recognition, identification, fieldofview

I want to calculate the DRI ranges of a camera using it's **resolution, focal length , sensor pixel pitch and target real size**. I have these values but I didn't find any equations to calculate **DRI** range values.

for example:
I have a camera with the below specifications

**Resolution**         :  640x480;
**Focal length**      :  70 mm;
**sensor pixel pitch** :  12 um;
**Target size**        :  0.5 meter x 0.5 meter (width x height);

approx. DRI ranges for the above camera is:

**Detection**          :  1940 meters;
**Recognition**        :  490 meters;
**Identification**     :  240 meters;

**the above values are generated using online DRI calculators

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate DRI ranges you need to do the following:

(focal length * target size) / (your DRI criteria * (pixel pitch/1000))

Looks like the DRI criteria in your case is D=1.5pix, R=5.95pix, I=12.2pix, which is Johnson Criteria converted from line pairs to pixels as I see it interpreted by most people.